# How can I change the color of the line in the title page when using beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles, beamer-metropolis

I am using a beamer and the sample code is as below.

I want to change the color of the line on the title page which is orange. (to navy)

Is there any way I could do this?

Or is there any way I can change the overall color theme?

Thank you

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{Metropolis}
\subtitle{A modern beamer theme}
% \date{\today}
\date{}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Center for modern beamer themes}
% \titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.pdf}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
  \tableofcontents%[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure you are giving the xcolor package (which beamer loads) an option that defines the color you want. In this case, for "Navy", we can use the svgnames option.

You can pass options to xcolor from the beamer class by using `xcolor={...}` in the options for beamer:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}
```

Now you can set that color using `\setbeamercolor` for the element you want. In this case, at the end of the preamble, you can put:

```
\setbeamercolor{title separator}{fg=Navy}
```

For more on setting beamer colors, including using a different overall theme, see the [beamer user's guide](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), chapter 17.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the entire color theme by adding something like this to your preamble.

```tex
\usecolortheme{beaver}
```

For other options, look for 'Complete Color Themes' section in beamer user guide. However, you may not get the exact color you want (namely 'navy'). If you only care about that title separator, then the answer by @frabjous is the way to go.